# How to structure Views and ViewModels with user roles?

Tags: javascript, durandal, durandal-2.0

I'm working on an app that will require different views depending on the user role. Initially, I managed to separate my interaction with the API using a separate folder that contains the ajax request operations and models in order to avoid repeated code inside the VMs.

- `app/controllers/` - contains `GET`, `POST`, `PUT`, `DELETE` operations and models for each object

And then I have the structure for the rest of the application:

```
app/building/ [route:building/]
  - shell.html
  - shell.js
  - /offices (list of offices)
    - index.html
    - index.js
  - /equipment (list of equipments)
    - index.html
    - index.js

app/offices/ [route:offices/:id]
  - shell.html
  - shell.js
- /employees (list of employees)
  - index.html
  - index.js
- /details (office details)
  - index.html
  - index.js

app/employees/ [route:employees/:id]
  - shell.html
  - shell.js
  - /report (individual employee data)
    - index.html
    - index.js
  - /details (empoyee details)
    - index.html
    - index.js
```

This will be admin role. As you can see, a lot of shells, sub-shells, child routers and routes. And changes will need to be made because not all roles will have access to the same routes.

At first, I tried the viewURL approach, where I save the role at the beggining of the session and just serve the appropriate view using `viewUrl`, but then I noticed that the files were getting too bloated:

- had to make changes to the main router and child router and remove declared routes for lower level users
- separate views for each page (admin.html, employee.html) all sharing the same view model that contains functions that will never be used by the employee

Then I came up with another structure. It's the same as before, except each role will have their own folders:

```
app/roles/admin/
  - building/
    - ...
  - offices/
    - ...
  - employees/
    - ...
app/roles/employee
  - building/
    - ...
  - offices/
    - ...
  - employees/
    - ...
```

When the app loads I just set the root according to the role and it's done.

#### Advantages

- easier to maintain individually
- no role check beyond app start
- role specific code, no risk of messing something up for other roles

#### Disadvantages

- more files
- harder to maintain as a group. For example, if I rewrite a function that is shared amongst all roles, I have to replace that code for each role

I feel more confortable with the second structure, but I wanted to know what you guys thought. Or if you have a better way of handling roles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of different ways you could approach this (e.g. customising the `viewLocator.convertModuleIdToViewId` method comes to mind), but I think what you've got is OK provided you're not repeating too much code between the "same" view/viewModel for each different role.

The only thing I don't like about it is that you'll end up with "hundreds" of files named "index.js" and "index.html" which makes it hard to find if you're using R#.

In order to get around the "harder to maintain as a group" problem, you could fairly easily refactor common code out into an "All" role, and then require it in for specific roles. So something like:

```
app/roles/all/
  - building/
    - buildingCore.js
  - offices/
    - officesCore.js
```

Then for `buildingCore.js` (obviously I'm just making up the methods up here):

```
define([], function() {
    var someCommonBuildingFunction = function() {
        // whatever
    }

    return {
        doSomething: someCommonBuildingFunction
    }
});
```

And then in (say) `admin/building/building.js`:

```
define([
    "roles/all/buildingCore"
],

function(buildingCore) {
    var viewModel = {
        activate: function() {
            buildingCore.doSomething()
        }
    }

    return viewModel;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The index thing is pretty annoying I'll have to do something about that, probably give up on some of the folders. And regarding the repeated code, most of my functions in my VMs deal with operations such as add/edit/delete and they just call the functions inside my controllers folder. But I'll surely use your 'core' approach to further minimize the repetitions. Thanks again!